# Scheduled task even if the app is killed

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to run an NSTimer task:

```
    timerUploadData = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60 * 1, target: self, selector: "uploadData", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But it only work when we have the app in background, but I wan't to still run this even if the app is stopped by doing double tap on home and slide the app to the top to kill it. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the user kills the app, it is no longer running, therefore your code is no longer running. There is no such state that your code/app can be in where this is possible.

I think you should read the [app life cycle document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html).

Comment: So how Facebook is doing this ? How we still get notification ?

Comment: its called remote push notification, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

what are you trying to accomplish ! it may help solving you problem

Comment: Hmm okay, but I need something, a service working at background, because I do a send SOAP service, so if they're no connection I wan't to send the data id the connection is back again, it is possible ?